# How to get the type of inner function for the return type of outer function?

Tags: typescript

It would be convenient to not have to change the return type of fn0 each time I modify the type of fn1.  Is there any way to do this in TypeScript?

```
export function fn0(): typeof fn1 {

    return function fn1(): any {
    }
}
```

Comment: Automatic type inference does not work in your case? If so, can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I see.  I didn't know about automatic type inference.  That solves it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `typeof fn1`:

```
export function fn0() {

    return function fn1(): any {
    }
}
```

This is automatic type inference.